# Adding conditional comparison of two columns in relationship

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to put value comparision while creating relationship. When i give direct value that works perfectly fine.  but i wanted to pass column name with alias to get required results.

**This is working fine**

```
$this->query->add_where(
        $this->options['group'],
        db_and()
          ->condition("class.end_time", 1625047346 , '<=')
    );
```

**output** 
WHERE ((( (class.end_time <= 1625047346) ))AND ...............

**This is not working. it takes alias.column as value**

```
$this->query->add_where(
        $this->options['group'],
        db_and()
          ->condition("class.end_time", "class1.end_time" , '<=')
    );
```

**output** 
WHERE ((( (class.end_time <= 'class.end_time') ))AND ...............

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I just passed all the conditions as an extra text after join and it works.

This is how I passed text while joining two tables. You can pass extra while constructing join as a fifth parameter.

```
class mymodule_booking_classes_relationship  extends views_handler_relationship {

    function query() {
    
        $extra = "class.end_time <=  class1.start_time  ";
        $extra .= " or class.start_time >= class1.end_time ";

        $join3 = new views_join;
        $join3->construct('class_table', 'node', 'nid', 'course_id', $extra, 'INNER'); 
        $this->alias = $this->query->add_relationship('class1', $join3, 'class1');

    }
}
```